# Crash report when user accesses the addressbook

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

`Incident Identifier: 236B9D70-0A5E-49B4-8A60-797CC9FEFF2B`
`CrashReporter Key:   38c652a88ce03779805e96d5c4e36f9df820deba`

`Hardware Model:      xxx`

`Process:         LuckyOne [3493]`

`Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/7878C92C-5629-4163-AA84-B1D1C6676D2A/LuckyOne.app/LuckyOne`

`Identifier:      LuckyOne`

`Version:         ??? (???)`

`Code Type:       ARM (Native)`

`Parent Process:  launchd [1]`

`Date/Time:       2013-06-26 15:24:11.148 -0700`

`OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)`

`Report Version:  104`

`Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)`

`Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000000defe`

Crashed Thread:  1

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a436e30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a436fd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3208e2b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3208cfd6 __CFRunLoopRun + 814
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32000238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x320000c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   GraphicsServices                0x35bbb336 GSEventRunModal + 70
7   UIKit                           0x33f1c2b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
8   LuckyOne                        0x0003e42e 0x3c000 + 9262
9   LuckyOne                        0x0003e3e4 0x3c000 + 9188

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x31ffa68a CFRelease + 18
1   LuckyOne                        0x00040830 0x3c000 + 18480
2   LuckyOne                        0x0004036e 0x3c000 + 17262
3   AddressBook                     0x318618d0 __37-[ABTCC accessRequestWithCompletion:]_block_invoke_0 + 24
4   TCC                             0x3776455e __TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke_038 + 314
5   libxpc.dylib                    0x3a4877a6 _xpc_connection_call_reply + 22
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a371652 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 274
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a3717d4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 88
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a3957ee _pthread_wqthread + 358
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a395680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a4375d0 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a372d22 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 806
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a36e374 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 32

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a447d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a395ad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a3957f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a395680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a436e30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a436fd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3208e2b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3208d02c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32000238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x320000c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x37fe4390 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a3a00de _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a39ffa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a447d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a395ad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a3957f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a395680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a436e30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a436fd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3208e2b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3208d02c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32000238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x320000c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                      0x3294d888 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 304
7   Foundation                      0x329d122c __NSThread__main__ + 968
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a3a00de _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a39ffa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a447d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a395ad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a3957f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a395680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a447594 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x32092474 __CFSocketManager + 676
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a3a00de _pthread_start + 306
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a39ffa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a447d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a395ad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a3957f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a395680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 1 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0xffffffff      r2: 0x00000007      r3: 0x00000001
    r4: 0x1e836370    r5: 0x1e836390      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x00240e60
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x00000039     r10: 0x3a5b51e4     r11: 0x3a5b51e4
    ip: 0x3a5a06c4    sp: 0x00240e2c      lr: 0x00040835      pc: 0x31ffa68a
  cpsr: 0x60000030`
```

Comment: can you please post some code also so that at least we get the idea why it is crashing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appeared you are trying to release an addressbook object with CFRelease without checking if it is null or not.